# How to close the tab when closing the form brought to tab control from a different project

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have 2 different projects: main screen (like selection screen) and modules. The Modules project is available as a reference in my Home screen project. I have a tab control on my home screen and forms opened from different projects are displayed in this tab control.

What I want to do;
When the form opened in the tab control is selected and closed on the selection screen, I want the tab under the tab control to be closed. But I want to do this at the closing event of the closed form.

[When the form comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwKTP.jpg)

[While the form is closing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZPz9.jpg)

Form call operation works with the following function:

`Private Sub OpenForm (ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs)`

```
    Dim NameofTab As New TabPage ()
    Dim FormOpened As Integer
        If FormName <> "" Then 'I get the name of the form with a Sql query

            Dim formAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (WhichClass)
            Dim typeOfForm = formAssembly.GetType (WhichClass + "." + FormName)
            Dim form As Form = CType (Activator.CreateInstance (typeOfForm), Form)

            FormOpened = 0

            For x As Integer = 0 To Application.OpenForms.Count - 1
                If Application.OpenForms (x) .Name = FormName Then
                    FormOpened = 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            If FormOpened = 1 Then 'If the form is opened, it will make the selection process.
                Dim sayy As Integer
                Dim i As New TabControl.TabPageCollection (Me.MainTab)
                For sayy = 0 To i.Count - 1
                    If MainTab.TabPages (sayy) .Text = form.Text Then
                        MainTab.SelectedTab = MainTab.TabPages (sayy)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

            Else 'If the form is closed, it will open with a new tab in the MainTab.

                MainTab.Visible = True
                NameofTab.Text = e.Node.Text
                MainTab.TabPages.Add (NameofTab)
                NameofTab.Name = e.Node.Text

                form.TopLevel = False
                form.Visible = True

                MainTab.TabPages (e.Node.Text) .Controls.Add (form)
                form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
                MainTab.SelectedTab = NameofTab

            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub`
```

I have no idea about the code that should be written to close the tab page in the closing event of the form I called. I have to reach the MainTab tool at the main screen, which is a different project, in the closing event of a form in a different project.

Comment: Please add the relevant snippet(s) of source code to your question. That would help identify what's causing the issue

Comment: Previously the projects were unified and we could access the Tab control tool in the Main entrance with a Standard syntax as follows:
    <code>MainScreen.MainTab.TabPages.Remove(Mainscreen.MainTab.SelectedTab)</code>
But now the Projects are separated and I don't know how to get the information about the Tab control tool in a different project.

Comment: @Athrsizi add the information, including the code, in the question itself. We can't guess what your code does - how it added the tabs, why it didn't remove them or why closing another form should have anything to do with the tabs in the original form. We don't even know what Tab control was used

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?